# What are advantages of using JSON/XML over a plain string of variable format?

Tags: xml, json

What are advantages of using JSON/XML over a plain string of variable format?

We have an iPhone application where we are receiving a string of variables as a response to our post to an url rather then using JSON/XML from the server.

What would be some of the advantages to us being passed the data in JSON/XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON enables the transmission of structured data, that you don't have to parse client side.

It's useful when you have an html/js client which uses those data to build/fill the interface, as the data are automatically in the format you'll need in your js code.

Server side, it's easy to encode/decode too, as all major languages now have efficient libraries.

Prefer JSON over XML as it is both more human readable and lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Structure, regularity, standardization. Making parsing/querying trivial, too.

Answer (score 0):

JSON/XML has the standard format so you can easily find the library to parse the content.

Answer (score 0):

The advantages are (a) you don't have to design it yourselt, it's already been done, and (b) you don't have to write a parser yourself, it's already been done.