# Zend Framework: Return view as JSON

Tags: zend-framework

so my question is: What would be the best way to return the html of a response as JSON encoded string?

I know there are the typical json action helpers but they dont fit my need.

What i need is a way to return the complete html of a view as a json string if the request is an ajax-request.
Because i want to change my app to only load the content of the main container and i also need to pass along a few other variables during the request i need to find a way to do so :)

Maybe someone has already had some experience with that!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775494/what-are-advantages-of-using-json-xml-over-a-plain-string-of-variable-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775494/what-are-advantages-of-using-json-xml-over-a-plain-string-of-variable-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose another solution:

1 - create a `plugins` directory in `application` directory.
In this directory create the plugin `POutput.php` like that:

```
<?php
class Application_Plugin_POutput extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {           
        if (Zend_Registry::get('Output_Json'))
            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('layout_json');
    }
}
```

2 - Create a new layout "layout_json.phtml" like that:

```
<?php 
echo $this->json($this->layout()->content); ?>
```

You can see the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.json) for options about this helper

3 - Call the plugin in the `bootstrap` like that:

```
protected function _initPlugins(){
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_POutput());
}
```

4 - In the bootstrap, for example, initiate the variable `Output_Json` like that:

```
protected function _initJson(){
    Zend_Registry::set('Output_Json', true); // true for Json output, False for Html output
}
```

With this method, you do not have to change all your controller. ;)

I hope that answers your question. :)

Comment: Thanks but still that would require to change every controller.
Thats exactly what i dont want.
It has to be dynamic so that after each request, probably in the postDispatch() method, that the returned content is outputtet as a json array like {"html": "<div>im the content</div>", "activepage": "index"}.
So i need to be able to pass other variables in the json return

Comment: I change the answer. :)

Comment: Hey! That seems to be a good solution.
I need to create an ajax based application so that i only load the content that i need and not the complete menu, breadcrumb and stuff.
With the method you provided i can work something out. I have to change some things so because i still need to pass the breadcrumbs or the active page within the returned json array but that shouldnt be a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the best way, but I'll give you mine.

To send a json to ajax call, I do it in the controller. I disable the layout, view, and I send the json.

for example to send an array, I do:

```
public function fooAction() {
    $this->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    ...
    //get array $auth with value $authentification
    $auth = array('authentification' => $authentification);

    return $this->_helper->json($auth);
}
```

And it works very well :)

Comment: Yeah but this only works for the very specific controller.
What i need is, that every request that is sent to the project needs to be returned as json regardless which controller and action is called.
So it needs to work "automatically" for every controller/action.
It should looke something like:

{
  "html": "<div id =\"content\">Side Content</div>",
  "activepage": "index"
}

Comment: I 'll make a new answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Json response that interacts with your Model layer, you should use this:

```
return new JsonModel(array);
```

And if you need a simple response, you should use the Response class, like this:

```
$response   = new Response();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaders(
    array(
        'Content-type' => 'application/json'
    ));
$response->setContent($yourContent);

return $response;
```

Comment: And how would this be implemented to be used for every controller?
Im currently using a plugin that gets the content of the view in the postDispatch() method and then returns a json string.